# Need a linux command to search a particular file in all directories

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to search for a particular file name "i2need.txt" in all directories.

I tried this:

```
find * -type f
```

But I am getting all the files present in the directories.

I need only the i2need.txt file. Can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this question correctly you should just be able to start the search at the root directory `/`:

```
find / -name <filename>
```

Of course you'll likely get a lot of permission-related errors but the files' paths you have access to should be on `stdout`. 
You can also filter out the errors with `2> /dev/null` (redirecting it to `/dev/null`, effectively dropping it).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately

```sh
locate i2need.txt
```

You might need to do this first

```sh
sudo updatedb
```